# How can I find published essays by British undergradute IR university students?

Tags: publications, journals

I'm trying to find undergraduate coursework essays that have been published in a journal. I'm looking specifically for international relations essays or if not possible, politics essays.

Comment: What is the intended use for these essays? Depending on what you are trying to achieve, there may be alternative resources.

Comment: If found I'll read the essays to better understand how to write an academic essay for IR topics.

Comment: In response to your comment, I have enlarged my answer below. I suggest that you actually edit the body of your question to include your purpose in asking. It makes a huge difference.

Comment: Is your goal for your writing to sound like an undergraduate, or to sound like an academic? If the latter, then maybe all you need to do is find published, peer-reviewed articles on the topic of interest.

Answer (score 3):

I have never seen anything in any journal, in any discipline, to announce specifically that an article was written by an undergraduate student. It is not something that would usually be of any interest to anyone. Given that, the likelihood that you are going to discover from a journal that:

- a paper was written by an undergraduate, ***and***
- that it was originally written as a class essay

is, I think, vanishingly small.

If your aim, as you suggest in your added comments, is simply so that you can understand what is required from a good undergraduate essay in IR, I suggest that you talk to one of your professors/lecturers. I used to keep (with the permission of the student authors, of course) a collection of good essays written by different students on various topics specifically so that I could use them as examples of good writing. ... and I've since heard several other academics say that they do the same.